# Convert date from dutch to english

Tags: php, magento, date

I thought this going to be quite easy but it is not!
I have date:
mei 28, 2015 (dutch) and I would like to convert it to english Y-m-d

Problem is site is multilang so I would like it to stay dynamic (replace mai to may) is not solution, I've already tryed:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); 
echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($value));
```

or

```
 $date = date_parse(($value));
  print_r($date);
```

but all the time I'm getting:
1970-01-01

any ideas?

I'm trying to achieve this in magento, so maybe there is magento function for this

Comment: Are you passing in $value as the string 'mei 28,2015'? 
strtotime only support English I'm afraid.

Comment: yes $value is mei 28,2015, and I'm trying to find way to convert it to englsih

Comment: Have you considered just doing a string replace for the month. There are only 12 and a simple function with a case would do this. Once translated then strtotime etc should then work.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat it is 12 for 1 language only, site is multilanguage

Comment: @dfg5rte4 aha in that case my solution blows. I will be interested to see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use strptime() function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php

```
$value = 'mei 28, 2015';
$format = '%B %d, %Y';
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');    
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');

// get the array with date details 
$result = strptime($value, $format);
$day = str_pad($result['tm_mday'] + 1, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$month = str_pad($result['tm_mon'] + 1, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$year = $result['tm_year'] + 1900;

print $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
```

Comment: strftime('%F %d %Y') returns 2015-05-15 15 2015